# How to extract a specific text of an already extracted XML text in bash script

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed

I managed to extract a value from a XML file:

```
<--more labels up this line>
<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastVMSelected" value="14cd3204-4774-46b8-be89-cc834efcba89"/>
<--more labels and text down this line-->
```

by using this:

```
  UUID=$(sed -ne '/name="GUI\/LastVMSelected"/s/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' inputfile.xml)
       echo $UUID
```

I have this result in console:

```
14cd3204-4774-46b8-be89-cc834efcba89
```

That's it! But now, I need to use that UUID to get to another part of the same XML file, that I didn't show before. I simplified the XML file just to show the most relevant labels:

```
      <--more labels up this line>
 <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastVMSelected" value="14cd3204-4774-46b8-be89-cc834efcba89"/>
      <--more labels and text down this line-->
      <MachineEntry uuid="{14cd3204-4774-46b8-be89-cc834efcba89}" src="Machines/SomeMachine/SomeMachine.xml"/>
 <--more labels and text down this line-->
```

**I need to get "SomeMachine"** without extension, only that name. I tried myself adding some lines:

```
UUID=$(sed -ne '/name="GUI\/LastVMSelected"/s/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' inputfile.xml)    
LastVMname=$(sed -ne '/MachineEntry uuid="{'$UUID'}"/s/.*src="Machines\([^"]*\).xml".*/\1/p' inputfile.xml)
    echo $LastVMname
```

But I get this output:

```
/SomeMachine/SomeMachine
```

and I don't how to get rid of /SomeMachine/SomeMachine, just need "SomeMachine". Sed documentation is quite confusing :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alternate delimiter for the substitute command and key on the slash in the data.

```
LastVMname=$(sed -ne '/MachineEntry uuid="{'$UUID'}"/s|.*src="Machines.*/\(.*\).xml".*|\1|p' inputfile.xml)
```

However, [this way madness lies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

You should use an XML parser such as [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). Something like:

```
uuid=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//ExtraDataItem[@name='GUI/LastVMSelected']" -v @value)
LastVMname=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//MachineEntry[uuid='$uuid'] -v @src)
LastVMname=${LastVMname##*/}    # strip up to and including the last slash
LastVMname=${LastVMname%.*}     # strip the extension
```